# Gold badge user dupehammers question then updates his own answer on the linked duplicate

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I asked a question about how to determine if a Map is indeed a Map. Specifically I am having problems with `instanceof` between window contexts (realms, if you like).

Anyway my question [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39962073/determining-if-an-object-is-a-map-in-javascript). The user that closed the question then [updated their original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29926193/revisions) and [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29924932/revisions) to be about both Sets and Maps.

Is it okay to close a question as a duplicate and then update an already existing question and answer in another post in order to actually make it a duplicate?

Comment: Why not actually?

Comment: Well, I see how they are related, but just reading the two questions (pre-edit), I really don't see how they are duplicates.

Comment: @robbmj duplicate is for answers, not questions. If his answer answered your question... yes, it's a dupe.

Comment: Seems totally fine and good for me. It seems here the user just generalized and improved his answer, which is a good thing and if the answer from the duplicate answers your question then it's a dupe.

Comment: It's not like duplicates count against you in any way.

Comment: @Patrice what? ["There are many ways to **ask the same question**, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates) That two questions have 1 similar answer doesn't mean they are duplicates, instead ["two questions are duplicate pretty much when they have the same answer**s**."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95828/213575) See also http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/956/58982

Comment: @Braiam so... "his answer on a previous post answers your question" != "has the same answer"? To me, we are talking about the exact same thing here... And.... don't know enough about the gaming subcommunity to know how their duplicate rules apply, but still, interesting read.

Comment: @Patrice the handling of duplicates is the same on all communities (see the dates of the posts, most of the stuff we presume is based on those old posts). I'm challenging your assertion that "same answer" == "duplicated questions", **having the same answers is not enough to make two questions duplicates**.

Comment: @Braiam oh I was not challenging the pertinence, simply saying I do not know enough about it to say with certitude this is the fact. And to me, if the same answer can be posted verbatim to two questions and apply in full there..... yes, they are duplicates. I don't see an example where we could have the same answer to two questions and NOT have them be duped, or where it would still make sense to leave them de-duped

Comment: @Patrice you got a [example on those post](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/956/58982): *"I asked for [an atomic UNIX operation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70/) on unix.se, and got the answer I was looking for - mkdir. It would be ridiculous if a question about how to create folders got closed as a duplicate of mine!"*

Comment: @Braiam I don't see how the mkdir answer, if it's a real (read, complete and addressing everything about the question) answer to the semaphore/lock question, can apply in full to "how do I create folders", but maybe that's what you hint at as "needs more than just the answers"

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to make duplicate target more general/canonical to cover more questions.

In this particular case edit was not strictly necessary as duplicate provided all guidance necessary to check type. While there could be some subtle differences one should be able to adjust code as necessary. Checking for different type is not as bad as claiming something like following but close

> "all `for` samples use `i` as variable, but I need to use `j` - don't close as duplicate unless it is exact!!!"...

Also there is nothing wrong with duplicates from *the site's point of view*. Indeed that are some drawbacks for OP - if OP should have found one themselves they get downvotes, they no longer can provide self-answer, there will be less quick votes in general as post has solution, duplicate is less personalized than copy-paste ready answer tailored to OP case...

Comment: `Also there is nothing wrong with duplicates from the site's point of view.`  If the new duplicates are written in such a way that they're likely to attract views that wouldn't otherwise have found the canonical, sure.  If not, then they aren't.